# Create new array from another

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array:

```
Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [101] => Array
                (
                    [odata] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 1
                            [2] => 1
                            [3] => 1
                        )

                )

            [200] => Array
                (
                    [odata] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 1
                            [2] => 1
                            [3] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [rjad] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => red
                    [1] => blue
                    [2] => green
                )

        )

)
```

in this array [rjad] key = [odata] key, and [odata] value = second key in [rjad].

What i want is to create new array from old one with user ids values in second array:

like this:

```
[rjad] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => red
                        [1] => Array
                                   (
                                     [blue] => Array
                                               (
                                                 [0] => 101
                                                 [1] => 200
                                                )
                        [2] => green
                    )

            )
```

Struggling already 3 hours with no success. Any ideas how to get it are very wellcome.

Image do explain relatinships
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/phparray.jpg/

Comment: Explain how logically related data in "user" to data in "rjad".

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Relation are as follows<br> [users][101][odata][1]=>1  equals [rjad][2][1] => blue

Comment: if you want the keys from `$users` array, just use `array_keys` to get them. Link to docs: [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: I am not sure how array_merge or array_keys to apply simply in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd seriously rethink your structure, but here's a working (if ugly) solution

```
foreach ($users as $userId => $user) {
    foreach ($user['odata'] as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($rjad[$key][$value])) {
            if (!is_array($rjad[$key][$value])) {
                $colour = $rjad[$key][$value];
                $rjad[$key][$value] = array();
                $rjad[$key][$value][$colour] = array();
            } else {
                reset($rjad[$key][$value]);
                $colour = key($rjad[$key][$value]);
            }
            $rjad[$key][$value][$colour][] = $userId;
        } 
    }
}
```

Working demo -> http://codepad.viper-7.com/IEcpvU

Based on comments seems you may want a separate array, which is easily solved

```
// copy the array and act on it instead of directly on $rjad
$result = $rjad;
foreach ($users as $userId => $user) {
    foreach ($user['odata'] as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($result[$key][$value])) {
            if (!is_array($result[$key][$value])) {
                $colour = $result[$key][$value];
                $result[$key][$value] = array();
                $result[$key][$value][$colour] = array();
            } else {
                reset($result[$key][$value]);
                $colour = key($result[$key][$value]);
            }
            $result[$key][$value][$colour][] = $userId;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work because 'users' and 'rjad' are different keys pls check img http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/phparray.jpg/

Comment: @drupal2000, Have you actually tried it? Based on the arrays you provided, it returns the result you're expecting. The mapping above is on the odata keys not the user id keys.

Comment: Sorry, but your code will not work, because i do not see how you get data from [rjad] . There is array $somearray and it consists of $somearray['users'] and $someaaray['rajd']. Your code dealing only with $somearray['users'] . I want to get new array from tese both. I do not understand from where you get $rjad in you code above?

Comment: @drupal2000, I've added a link to the working demo of the code in my answer, look at the result, it's identical to your desired output. If you're saying you want a new array, instead of transposing the values in $rjad, that's doable too, but that's not what you indicated from the question, perhaps you could clarify. But I maintain, the result of the above code is an array matching exactly with your stated expectation

Comment: My bad) I did not understand fistly that you splitted ther array. Thx a lot, you code is workink like a sharm! But why do you think that the stracture is bad? Bad for perfomance?

Comment: @drupal2000, cool, glad it's working. The structure is difficult to follow with all the nesting, it took me a while to figure out the relationships, and it isn't helped by using numeric keys and values to map to non obvious associated keys in other arrays. You'll come back to the code one day and have a hard time figuring it out, trust me.  But hey, if you're comfy with it, who am I to judge :)

Comment: Unfortunetly i do not see other way to get what i need. You are really a great expert in php arrays, thx a lot for help!

Comment: Like I said, if you're ok with it, that's all that matters, it's all about getting the job done, right? :D. (ps, don't forget to accept the answer that helped you ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear - what is the relationship between rjad...blue and those user accounts from the other array? Is item 0 in the odata arrays the default colour?

Comment: sorry that was supposed to be a question, not an answer - first time!

Comment: I added picture to post to explaine relationships